# Optimizing code to run faster and more efficient

Tags: mysql, rows

I'm trying to find a way to optimize my code to run faster. I have a lot of select statements (about 30+ select queries) and then I use `UNION ALL` to connect all of those select statements. I know its a horrible way of doing it. How can I improve it? Here's the link if you want to see the results: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db3e7b/1

Here's an example of my code:

```
SELECT 'east/flw' AS LOCATION, 
  ROUND(sum(CASE WHEN t2.locid = '2815' THEN t2.value ELSE 0 END), 2) AS Reading,
  ROUND(sum(CASE WHEN t2.locid = '2620' THEN t2.value ELSE 0 END), 2) AS Flw,
  ROUND(sum(CASE WHEN t2.locid = '2618' THEN t2.value ELSE 0 END), 2) AS Prs,
  ROUND(sum(CASE WHEN t2.locid = '2595' THEN t2.value ELSE 0 END), 2) AS Lvl

FROM table2 t2

INNER JOIN table1 t1
  ON t1.id = t2.locid
WHERE t2.t_stamp = (SELECT MAX(t2.t_stamp) 
                    FROM table2 t2 
                    WHERE t1.id = t2.locid)
GROUP BY 'east/flw'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'west/flw' AS LOCATION, 
  ROUND(sum(CASE WHEN t2.locid = '2715' THEN t2.value ELSE 0 END), 2) AS Reading,
  ROUND(sum(CASE WHEN t2.locid = '2720' THEN t2.value ELSE 0 END), 2) AS Flw,
  ROUND(sum(CASE WHEN t2.locid = '2718' THEN t2.value ELSE 0 END), 2) AS Prs,
  ROUND(sum(CASE WHEN t2.locid = '2795' THEN t2.value ELSE 0 END), 2) AS Lvl

FROM table2 t2

INNER JOIN table1 t1
  ON t1.id = t2.locid
WHERE t2.t_stamp = (SELECT MAX(t2.t_stamp) 
                FROM table2 t2 
                WHERE t1.id = t2.locid)

GROUP BY 'west/flw'
UNION ALL
.
.
.
UNION ALL
.
.
.
```

Comment: tables description?? explain command? indexes? PK and FK?

Comment: the table is in the link provided. and i can't make any changes to the table on my actual database

Comment: I dind't see any PK,FK, UK, index, etx in the sqlfiddle, if you can't modify the table how do you expect to speed up a simple query?

Comment: @jcho360 PK is id and locid. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db3e7b/1 as much as i want to modify the table on my actual database, i'm not allowed to. is there another way to speed up the query without modifying the table?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to throw out all `UNION ALL` and read tables only once,
in this way:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
         WHEN t2.locid IN ( '2815', '2620', '2618', '2595' )         
         THEN 'east/flw' 
         WHEN t2.locid IN ( '2715', '2720', '2718', '2795' )
         THEN 'west/flw'
         .......
         .......
         .......
         .......
  END AS LOCATION, 

  ROUND(sum(CASE WHEN t2.locid IN ( '2815', '2715', ............. ) 
                 THEN t2.value ELSE 0 END), 2) AS Reading,
  ROUND(sum(CASE WHEN t2.locid IN ('2620', '2720', ............... )
                 THEN t2.value ELSE 0 END), 2) AS Flw,
  ROUND(sum(CASE WHEN t2.locid IN ('2618', '2718', ...............)
                 THEN t2.value ELSE 0 END), 2) AS Prs,
  ROUND(sum(CASE WHEN t2.locid IN ('2595', '2795', ...............)
                 THEN t2.value ELSE 0 END), 2) AS Lvl
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1
  ON t1.id = t2.locid
WHERE t2.t_stamp = (SELECT MAX(t2.t_stamp) 
                    FROM table2 t2 
                    WHERE t1.id = t2.locid)
GROUP BY location
```